# Add object to the database without calling save

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I would like to know if it is possible to add an object to the database without calling save().

```
            foo = Foo.objects.create(
                #fields
            )

            lst_bars = []
            for bar in MyModel.objects.filter(
                #fields
            ):
                lst_bars.append(Bar(
                    foo_id=foo.id,
                    # fields
                ))

            Bar.objects.bulk_create(lst_bars)

            foo.save()
```

In this code I'm creating Foo, then using its id as a reference when creating Bar. After bulk creating all Bar objects, I call the foo save.

In the foo save() I call each bar save(), then aggregate all bars data and fill the Foo fields.

In total the method save is being called two times, but in the create() I would like to just create without saving, that way it wouldn't make calculations when there is no data.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to call the save and not make the calculations:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.full_clean()
    just_created = True if not self.id else False
    if not just_created:
        # make calculations
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Would still appreciate if anyone knows if it's possible to add an object to the database without calling save in another way (without having to change the save method).

Comment: you don't have to call `save` in `bulk_create` it's not supported

Comment: I don't want to call save in bulk_create. What I'm trying to do is not call save in the create() -> (foo = Foo.objects.create(#fields))

Comment: if you don't want to call save you can do that without overriding as well just call the constructor  `foo = Foo( #fiels and all...)` and defer the save method

Comment: But then if I do that, I'm not able to use it's id as a reference in the Bar(foo_id=foo.id)